# How to correctly handle partial write in Ruby Sockets?

Tags: ruby, sockets

TCP sockets are streams, not messages, so berkeley sockets `send()` function on some systems may send less data than required. Since Ruby Socket is very thin wrapper over berkeley sockets, AFAIK `Socket#send` will behave exactly like berkeley sockets `send()`. So what is the correct way to send a complete message via Ruby TCP sockets? In python it's a special function for that called `sendall()`. But in Ruby i need to manually write code like that:

```
while (sent = sock.send( data, 0 ) < data.length do
  data = data[ sent..-1 ]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what danielnegri says, `IO.write` ends up calling `io_binwrite` in `io.c`

The relevant bit of the [ruby source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/io.c#L865) is below (`n` and `len` are initially set to the length of your data and `offset` to 0)

```
retry:
arg.offset = offset; 
arg.length = n;

if (fptr->write_lock) {
  r = rb_mutex_synchronize(fptr->write_lock, io_binwrite_string, (VALUE)&arg);
}
else {
  long l = io_writable_length(fptr, n);
  r = rb_write_internal(fptr->fd, ptr+offset, l);
}
if (r == n) return len;
if (0 <= r) {
  offset += r;
  n -= r;
  errno = EAGAIN;
}
if (rb_io_wait_writable(fptr->fd)) {
  rb_io_check_closed(fptr);
  if (offset < RSTRING_LEN(str))
    goto retry;
}
return -1L;
```

As you can see, until it has written all the data it will keep on doing `goto retry` and trying again. `rb_io_wait_writable` basically checks that the value of `errno` is such that one should try again (as opposed to something more fatal) and then calls `select` to avoid busy-waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I used 'write' method:

```
require "socket"  
server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 20000)  
loop do  
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |s|  
    print(s, " is accepted\n")  
    server.write(Time.now)  
    print(server, " is gone\n")  
    server.close  
  end  
end
```

Try:

```
require 'socket'
sock = Socket.open(Socket::PF_INET,Socket::SOCK_STREAM,Socket::IPPROTO_TCP)
@data = "anyThing"
@addr = pack_sockaddr_in(port, host)
sock.connect(@addr)    #make the connection
sock.send(@data, 0)
```

You may also want to try using the TCPSocket class. I haven't used any of this Ruby code, so I'm not used to this particular library; please let me know if I got this all wrong.

```
require 'socket'
sock = TCPSocket.new(host, port)
@data = "anyThing"
sock.send(@data, 0)
```

Comment: Is it any evidence that `write` handles partial send?